# Automating commenting and uncommenting of sequential statements in a Teradata sql

Tags: sql, shell, teradata, qtp

I need to execute the following statement "`select a, b, c from tblname group by 1,2,3`" such that each column name is commented one by one (and the elements in group by are reduced correspondingly) . Eg:

Step 1:

```
   Select a
     ,b
    /*,c*/
   from table name GROUP BY
   1
   ,2
   /*,3*/
```

Step 2:

```
   Select a
     /*,b*/
    ,c
   from table name GROUP BY
   1
   ,2
   /*,3*/
```

and so on, and store the resulting count after commenting each column and then find out the Unique, Not Null columns, by comparing the result of each iteration. The no. of columns can rise up to 200 , depending upon the table.

Question: Can the commenting and uncommenting be automated in Teradata? Is UFT the best tool to automate such scripts or is shell scripting a better way?

Comment: You'll need to do this in some scripting language, whether that's a Teradata Stored Procedure, a bash script, a vbscript, or whatever... Other than that, though, this question is a little broad for SO.